# Why Typescript can't infer conditional type with Generics?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following code I understand that Typescript should be able to know that there is a possibility for `args` to have the `baz` prop, but it doesn't. It says:

> Property 'baz' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339)

```js
function func<T1, T2 = T1>(args: Foo<T1, T2>) {
  if ('baz' in args) {
    args.baz;
  }
}

type Foo<T1, T2> = {
  bar: string;
} & (T2 extends T1
  ? unknown
  : { baz: string }
);
```

So, why it says that type of `args` is `never` inside that `if` block?

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKSAeAKgRgDSPQJkQF49MA+ACgEMAnAcwGcAuRAMTjgxz3zIEpEAbwBQiRDGCIKAcgBGVAF7TxSWowEixYtQwB08hQG5RiAL7DzwqAE8ADgFM2HLrgJliQk-JosGUGjBgdMamiABkUgSI9gAeUPZgACYMpCYA-IjgANZgcADuYCYsgogGvv6BdGbCfIZAA) is the playground code for it.

### Edit 1

Adding a link to the code for the use case mentioned in the comments: [Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4CgpRiIoCMAXFKsAgJYB2A5gNy4C+uuokUAsiAEoRUYAPZ1U0LHgIATOMDgU6AV2QAjCAjYcA9DqgBRAB4owAG2giAZlGWo4DCLgDGYqlEfAAyiOQRgABb0DJhQzggQ8hAwymqosQDi-l6aAG40zhAAPPiwxGgANLl8gsJuTgB8ABTStghmFAAGOsggOsr1jUUEAI7KmiDwSGgUNYT5JFCsAJSYFVBjRMOTM91QmggiCEMSCFVU8nYAwiIyELO1BKgA7jTAzgELB8DHp+c4uQQEznASUAAsAAYAMxkT5fAgRF4IOhQADkAAlflA6CJCJpkDRUKgaGI4SwId9ftAgf8wYSvlCOrDGj4-IFglAZCIhHQ4cB1kYscBGgSvuxwVSYfD8blWEUZixcFZlHRnMBcbDwpFgNFYvE1ElvGkMtkACpDFCoApQPWlUTiCAms3+akAEXkcFCNrKluquREYAVbgoWoA8l7Fagsgb8sbTebytbBNC6A6FBUihdckLYb8QHKoDK5d7Ybt0pkqksjRRQ8NUNMKDBNpiJFkUggCxAY9SQy2YfG4BV5pcwm4OR0zKFPA2mwBVepVT251AAOkHJuLhSg06Ds76A0Ny9Xblnm2Uqq3FalEOoIA+FNc4g5EVdElLkctoTg1zgdygCOAwDAs88VQXOBQLcgRHBEZx0AqcBmKgFDUP0UzTHyEIWBycgKCehI0DYVRwreFoSAA6kgYCQAgcJQPQK6Bm4yYUrIjqhDu4h7kI+EQERcAkZoVR4eUiHggQrDrNB0C9hCaFOlgvFPsisoANaotcaboDasadkh-IcBSqYXnR8TOJk2KwQg-RrBSElmfyGlCT89yPFUGxbLRhI6WJXz6YZMFZlBEiWRCjkIBQSwSAYCCbHsAUmkxc4BTsmjTH5UzWWKLACtm8qKh4yQ6pkE5mCGR7ugQRCBBQVC0IwaxLl5ZZGmsG4IIMYYAPyjNVpZHrMGDzIIrgIDIWTlcEJryYpdCJimIgHtELVtWGHVhl1PUQH1A1DZVlDUMEE3OXos77ZQygkbeEAyFAZgiAwGRaVAOlwgEERWKKaWyhlYjjAgIVhVsVS5AFFCjSISlVYguwUAAQr8GSjrqAYzlkgNKRUADacKxaDmhwgAukmVZmPIVhbMgMOZKF4W6XtB3xMdQinedl3XSmtrCtgUB+NiDgQBQXhbYwDnfQgsysKlHD0KqCBWHAmRQCTzbM3QbaseUPa5B5QheWoIgiBYcB0HyEmtRGSuWnyAWGzA+PAITCDEzlEBk1sIu4GLmiS9LFsE0TssOwguns-YjhlbzzCqwoLyoCcZyGyo6iaPrjqG4jevaJw4DQP61HiAVYbRsbvlG2pjrzFgkM4s4stw0G2flvMABkuRVKp9oMRARiqnQMgqY+Ejgs1th0ApQN0OCFCs9JhHEaRozj1zRt3u83UF83CgIVKLsS1L0Cl9DduV241dGirBCDkHFUh5CU2HrNCztaanVzFAvVbGtwcmutDAVHyDVNeWhtFvNd9FoPyfv1Qar9+6DyRqbAWcUEB-2eK8M4ShVAaEFg-d+qUgA)

### Edit 2

Adding more examples ([Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgHgCoEYB8UC8UDeAUFFGAE4D2YAXFBoQL6GED0LdAEgJIDKUA6gHkASgGkehUJDoALAJYJ+FMgGsEadABo6AJmx4MUCAA9gEAHYATBLuJQA-LEQoMmO7XhIN2AGQEocOYUwDIQZAAKlDRQCMBkcuYA5lBMhABmAK7mAMbAchTmUADuymoa2qh6ABRUeQUItKjyiqXqGBV6AJQEdnJpUFUA5IHBoRFRg1AJULX55gjdRCQks-UAdORUANx2K2B182sjIWGR23ZMqWycvFAAYgCCXAAyElLQTQp3cHIANm1aXT6JxeVxQPxVQwmMxWGyVOyOLIqIJFczufzHMZnaKxeJJFKdZiZHIHKBpH7-cpAmr7OYNWRfCkAjqYRa9fpDTGnCZTQqreZs5YzWnrTZgLZQa78GQgKAAIn5CDlUxsFH673l5ggADcwsqxhB7PZdsKDggjkETuNziRLsxrgA5ACiAA1UNouKgoKIHYJ+HwHl7nk6HjwvagOIH5WLla7eKg+E6AGpOh0CT0ceV+JEo8zKrgO1BO4Q8J0AYVQXEEDrWtck4A+EFiuH8YtouISyQY4KgOYoqOY2XqwCgZlijSbI7wS1IUVog0GmkYzD6A2GlqxPOmY+AgtHk42UUl7C4I+ygTJCUs0aicsYQA)):

```js
type Base<T1> = {
  prop: T1
}

// THIS WORKS
type ThisWorks<T1, T2> = T1 extends T2
  ? Base<T1>
  : Base<T1> & { anotherProp: string }

function works<T1, T2>(options: ThisWorks<T1, T2>) {
  if ('anotherProp' in options) {
    options.prop;
    options.anotherProp;
  }
}

// THIS FAILS
type ThisFails<T1, T2> = Base<T1> & (T1 extends T2
  ? unknown
  : { anotherProp: string })

function fails<T1, T2>(options: ThisFails<T1, T2>) {
  if ('anotherProp' in options) {
    options.prop; // Why "options" is of type "never" here??
    options.anotherProp;
  }
}

// NEXT, IT KNOWS AT LEAST THAT "prop" EXISTS EVEN WITH "& unknown" INTERSECTION...
type Test = { prop: string } & unknown

const test: Test = {
  prop: '',
}

if ('anotherProp' in test) {
  test.prop // It can find "prop"
}
```

Comment: A conditional type like `T2 extends T1 ? unknown : { baz: string }` where `T2` and `T1` are generic type parameters is *deferred* by the compiler; it does not try to evaluate it until `T1` & `T2` are specified. Inside the `func()` function body, the compiler cannot see the possibility that `args` may have a `baz` property.  See [ms/TS#48243](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48243) for a similar issue. Then the [`in` type guard](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) unsoundly narrows `args` to `never`, which is a limitation of `in` narrowing.

Comment: Does that fully address your question?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz or clarifying that Typescript defers to compiler in that case, but I can't agree that it's not possible for it to see the possibility of existence of that `baz` prop since `Foo` explicitly add that field in its conditional type. If you tell me it's a limitation that could be removed in the future it's doable and I accept your answer, but I if goes through "it's not possible" argument I can't accept it

Comment: I mean, I'm even helping Typescript by narrowing it down with the `in` operator, it's not a JS limitation in that operator, it's a TS one, right?

Comment: These are all limitations of TS, yes.  When I say that the compiler "cannot see the possibility", that is a direct consequence of the fact that it does not try to evaluate it.  I don't know what there is to agree or disagree about; I'm just describing what is happening. I'm also not making a prediction about whether or not such limitations could be removed in the future.  If I write up an answer I can explain what is going on and where the limitations are, along with links to sources. If you are unhappy with that, I understand, but I don't know why that would imply not accepting my answer.

Comment: Aside: a call signature like `<T1, T2 = T1>(args: Foo<T1, T2>) => void` is problematic, since `Foo<T1, T2>` has no good inference site for either `T1` or `T2`.  Let's say I call `func({bar: "", baz: ""})`.  What do you expect `T1` and `T2` to be inferred as?  What actually happens is that `T1` and `T2` fail to be inferred, and the compiler defaults to `unknown`, and thus you get `Foo<unknown, unknown>`, which evaluates to `{bar: string}`, and the compiler rejects `baz` as an excess property in an object literal. See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1yvyw).  ...

Comment: ...What is the actual purpose of `func()`?  I assume it's a toy example, but is there an underlying use case where a call signature like this helps you?  The "standard" way of writing it would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKqDyN), with no generics and certainly no conditional types.  If you can demonstrate a use case where this refactoring doesn't help you, then maybe someone can suggest a better approach.  In any case, this is not what I'd consider the sort of idiomatic TS likely to be supported in the future.

Comment: Let me try to explain shortly my use case: I have an HTTP service factory that receives 3 generic types (TParams, TResponse and TReturnData), so when TReturnData is a different type than TResponse the function requires an wrapper function to be passed as an option along with other options. Actually I had it working with another approach, so the question is not how to solve the mentioned use case, but since I found this simpler syntax in the question compared to my previous one I wanted so badly that it could work

Comment: @jcalz I've added the link in the question for the code I mentioned in my previous comment, it's late here and tomorrow I'll check deeper your links, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `T2` does not extend from `T1` the type will be unknown, so might not contain the baz prop as you state in:

```
T2 extends T1
  ? unknown
  : { baz: string }
);
```

If for all the cases there is a baz prop there is no error:

```
function func<T1, T2 = T1>(args: Foo<T1, T2>) {
  if ('baz' in args) {
    args.baz
  }
}

type Foo<T1, T2> = {
  bar: string;
} & (T2 extends T1
  ? { baz: number }
  : { baz: string }
);
```

Regarding "Typescript should be able to know that there is a possibility for args to have the baz prop", type checking means that the code that will come in will comply with the type defined. There is a possibillity that args might have the baz prop in the code of the question, but the main purpose of type checking is to assure that the code fits in the types defined, not to be able to see if there is a possibility.

Comment: This is correct, but I think the question is about why doesn't it work although it's explicitly checked for with the `in` operator (control won't enter the `if` if `args` has no `bar` property...)

Comment: yes @FZs you're right in your statement